# Can Any LDAP library sync password from Active Dirctory?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm wondering If any one before used an LDAP library for fetching users and groups from active directory server Including user passwords and sync them to database or another LDAP server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
Active directory requires a password filter to be installed on every domain controller to be able to retreive an entry's password.

Several IDM synchronizaqtion products provide a Password Filter.
-jim

Comment: Can you give me a hint about these products hilighting free or low cost ones

Comment: IMHO, none of them are "low cost" that I am aware, that work for any implementation.  I did find these two, that appear to be "free" or "open": http://wiki.openiam.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6717855  and http://code.google.com/p/sha1hexfltr/.

Answer (score 0):

The password component of microsofts active directory can only be changed or authenticate passwords.

But there are a lot of people with your problem, how do they do this?

This is often solved by using "pass-through authentication". A specific script syncs the groups/users between, for instance, an openLdap server and an active directory server and you use pass-trough authentication to authenticate the user using the active directories authentication.

- Activate SASL in Openldap
- And use in the openldap server, for the user password the following string `{SASL}username@Activedirectoryserver`
  The openldap server will know that it will have to authenticate the password at the active directory server...

Is explained in perfect steps here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alextch/2012/04/25/configuring-openldap-pass-through-authentication-to-active-directory/

Solved?